# What is the correct format to use for Date/Time in an XML file

Tags: .net, xml, datetime

What format do I use for Date/Time when writing to an XML file using .NET? Do I simply use `DateTime.ToString()`, or do I have to use a specific format?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I always use the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (e.g. `2008-10-31T15:07:38.6875000-05:00`) -- `date.ToString("o")`. It is the [XSD date format](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats) as well. That is the preferred format and a [Standard Date and Time Format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), although you can use a manual format string if necessary if you don't want the 'T' between the date and time: `date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

EDIT: If you are using a generated class from an XSD or Web Service, you can just assign the DateTime instance directly to the class property. If you are writing XML text, then use the above.

Answer (score 47):

EDIT: This is bad advice. Use "o", as above. "s" does the *wrong thing*.

I always use this:

```
dateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("s");
```

This is correct if your schema looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="startdate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
```

Which would result in:

```
<startdate>2002-05-30T09:00:00</startdate>
```

You can get more information here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp

Comment: Keep in mind this converts the date to UTC. When you process the date, you must convert it back to your current timezone based on locale (unless you are processing everything in UTC). Also, usually you would put a 'Z' at the end to denote the date is UTC.

Comment: "s" works for me when calling a .net web service from soap ui.

Answer (score 5):

If you are manually assembling the XML string use `var.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffffZ"));`  That will output the official XML Date Time format.  But you don't have to worry about format if you use the built-in serialization methods.

Comment: jonnii's will return basicly the same result.

Comment: In this case all dates MUST be in UTC time zone otherwise usage of "Z" suffix is wrong.

Comment: I will repeat the prior comment - this is actually incorrect if the dt is not utc.

Answer (score 3):

What does the DTD have to say?

If the XML file is for communicating with other existing software (e.g., SOAP), then check that software for what it expects.

If the XML file is for serialisation or communication with non-existing software (e.g., the one you're writing), you can define it.  In which case, I'd suggest something that is both easy to parse in your language(s) of choice, and easy to read for humans.  e.g., if your language (whether VB.NET or C#.NET or whatever) allows you to parse ISO dates (YYYY-MM-DD) easily, that's the one I'd suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The `XmlConvert` class provides these kinds of facilities.
About DateTimes, in particular, be careful about obsolete methods.
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457718/1288109