# Convert string to DateTime with Convert.ToDateTime

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm a but frustrated. I'm playing around with xml-files. So this is my automatically created xml-File:

```
<Files>
<Lists>
    <oList>
      <Object>
        <Name>test1</Name>
        <DateCreated>2/11/2013 4:35:05 PM</DateCreated>
        <DateDeadline>2/17/2013 12:00:00 AM</DateDeadline>
        <Reward>none</Reward>
        <Description>chocolate amedei 9</Description>
      </Object>
    </oList>
  </Lists>
</Files>
```

The many start elements in the beginning have to be there because I want to extend the file later. So now I want to read this xml-file and create an object of a class (ThingsToDoObjects, it's supposed to become a to-do-list some day) that needs exactly the parameters stored in the xml-file. This Object should be stored in a list. So this is what I have so far:

```
XmlDocument xmlListDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlListDoc.Load(xmlFilePath);
            foreach (XmlNode xnode in xmlListDoc.SelectNodes("Files/Lists/oList/Object"))
            {
                string n = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText.ToString();
                DateTime c = Convert.ToDateTime(xnode.SelectSingleNode("DateCreated").InnerText.ToString());
                DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(xnode.SelectSingleNode("DateDeadline").InnerText.ToString());

                string r = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Reward").InnerText.ToString();
                string de = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Description").InnerText.ToString();
                ThingsToDoObjects NeuObject = new ThingsToDoObjects(n, c, d, r, de);
                o.Add(NeuObject);
            }
```

Now when I debug the following happens:
n is created fine, c is created fine. But d just doesn't work.It gives an error:

> "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

(That's my translation from German, so maybe the error might be called a bit different. What's going on there? I hope I just made some stupid mistake.

By the way: I tried the `ParseExactly()` method but it dind't work either and gave the same error.

Thanks in advance to everone who answers.

Comment: Have you tried using DateTime.TryParse() ?

Comment: Can you post the exact content of the string `xnode.SelectSingleNode("DateDeadline").InnerText.ToString()`?

Comment: I'm also beginner with this language, so sorry for my little question, maybe you allready did it but, : did you try datetime.parse(xnode.SelectSingleNode("DateCreated").InnerText.ToString())?

Comment: I didn't do parse yet, just exact parse. But what makes e wonder is that the same thing for for similar strings not the same.

Comment: The string xnode.SelectSingleNode("DateDeadline").InnerText.ToString() is what it says in the xml, 2/17/2013 12:00:00 AM. I know ToString() is not necessary there, it was just one of my frustrated attempts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm assuming you can't change the XML format itself. It would be *much* better to use a standard format, as suggested by dtb.)

If you've got text in a *known* format, use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`. They *will* work, if you give them the right format. I usually use the invariant culture for parsing in these cases too - you don't want a user culture's date separators etc to mess things up. In this case, it looks like the format string you want is `"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"`.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "2/17/2013 12:00:00 AM";
        string format = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
        DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact(text, format,
                                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                             DateTimeStyles.None);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

I'd also strongly suggest using LINQ to XML if you can. It'll make your XML handling a lot simpler than your current code.

Comment: Great, that works. Though I have some questions left: Why M/d/yyyy and not mm/dd/yyyy? And can you  tell me why my Convert.ToDateTime()-idea worked for one, but not the other? _It worked well for c, not for d. I find that strange.

Comment: So that's the link that answers all the questions concerning this I guess: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx. I really thank you for answering almost all of my few c# questions I've asked here so far. You really help me a lot, thank you for that.

Comment: @user1953145: It's more this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx - as for why `c` "worked" - it's probably because 2/11/2013 can be parsed as d/M/yyyy... whereas 2/17/2013 can't.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned translating from German, I'm going to assume that you're in Germany. You're probably trying to parse the date as "you". What I mean is that the date is being parsed using the German culture formatter (dd/mm/yyyy) and there is no 17th month to parse to.

Try using this instead:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

Comment: Gret, that worked fine either. But why 17th month. Is it done hexadecimal?

Comment: Because the date being parsed is 2/17/2013 12:00:00 AM, but the parser was trying to parse it as dd/mm/yyyy, the 17 was in the month position.

Comment: ahh, ok. that's confusing when you donÄt know it :-) . thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [standard  way to format date/time values in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254753/what-is-the-correct-format-to-use-for-date-time-in-an-xml-file-net):

```xml
<DateCreated>2013-11-02T04:35:05</DateCreated>
```

You can parse this format using the [XmlConvert.ToDateTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162342.aspx):

```
DateTime result = XmlConvert.ToDateTime("2013-11-02T04:35:05",
                                        XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
```

Or, better yet, have a look at [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and use the [XElement to DateTime Explicit Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343203.aspx):

```
DateTime result = (DateTime)obj.Element("DateCreated");
```