# XPath 1.0: Converting Timestrings

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

How can I convert Strings in this format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` into this format     `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`  using XPAth 1.0?

Comment: FYI: There is an prescribed XML date & time format.  The author of this XML file should be using that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254753/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, XPath 1.0 does not even support regular expression. Hence, I think you are stuck with using substring functions.

The following is not very elegeant, but it should work (`$date` being your input string). It split the different parts and reconstruct the string afterwards.

```
concat(
  substring-after(substring-after(substring-before($date, ' '), '/'), '/'),
  '/',
  substring-before(substring-after(substring-before($date, ' '), '/'), '/'),
  '/',
  substring-before(substring-before($date, ' '), '/'),
  ' ',
  substring-after($date, ' ')
)
```