# C# xml deserialization: InvalidOperationException (maybe namespace related?)

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I receive from another piece of code a MemoryStream object that contains an xml document and I need to deserialize it:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aaa:MyRootElement xmlns:aaa="http://www.example.com/config/1.0">
    <aaa:Configurations>
        <aaa:Configuration>
            <aaa:Field1>xxx</aaa:Field1>
            <aaa:Field2>abc</aaa:Field2>
        </aaa:Configuration>
    </aaa:Configurations>
</aaa:MyRootElement>
```

I wrote this code:

```
[XmlRoot("MyRootElement")]
public class ConfigInfo
{
    public class Configuration
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlElement("Configurations")]
    public List<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }

    public static ConfigInfo FromMemoryStream(MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        var r = new ConfigInfo();
        
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigInfo));
        r = (ConfigInfo)serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);   

        return r;
        
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it's giving me the following exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: <MyRootElement xmlns='http://www.example.com/config/1.0'> not expected.
```

I thing it has something to do with with the "aaa" namespace, but I have no clue on how to fix it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed Namespace attribute into your class. It should work now.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "MyRootElement", Namespace = "http://www.example.com/config/1.0")]
public class ConfigInfo
{
    [XmlElement("Configurations")]
    public List<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }

    public static ConfigInfo FromMemoryStream(MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        var r = new ConfigInfo();

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigInfo));
        r = (ConfigInfo)serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);

        return r;

    }

    public class Configuration
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }

        public string Field2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hugo, I figured it out yesterday evening. I already tried to add the Namespace attribute, but with "aaa" as value. I confirm that with the full url it's working.

Comment: @Disti `Configurations ` is serialized with an outer container element, so it is also necessary to replace `[XmlElement("Configurations")]` with `[XmlArray("Configurations"), XmlArrayItem("Configuration")]`, see e.g. Problem #1 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35712286) to [Nested objects not serialized in xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35710610) and also https://dotnetfiddle.net/gVMlvf.  With that as well as the  `XmlRoot.Namespace` setting, deserialization should work.