# how to convert sudo xml string to xml in php

Tags: php, xml, date

I have sudo string in a sort of xml format which i want to convert to xml in php. Which I then want to grab the `imaware` which contains date string in different formats and convert to appropriate date.

**sudo string**

```
<IMAware>
09-03-2016 05:28
</IMAware>

<NextUpdate>
</NextUpdate>

<ETR>
</ETR>

<SMS>
text
</SMS>

<Summary>
text
</Summary>

<Impact>
text
</Impact>

<Plan>
</Plan>

<Resolution>
text
</Resolution>

<Complete>
text
</Complete>

<Timeline>
text
</Timeline>

<Crisis>
</Crisis>
```

So far I have the following

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dbData); $i++) {
            try {
                print_r(trim($dbData[$i]['INCIDENT_NOTES']));
                $xml = simplexml_load_string (trim($dbData[$i]['INCIDENT_NOTES']));
                print_r($xml);
            } catch (Exception $e) { 
                echo $e; 
            }

            /*$items = $xml->xpath(item);

            foreach($items as $item) {
                echo $item['title'], ': ', $item['description'], "\n";
            }*/
        }
```

This fails with

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 5: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /var/SP/oiadm/docroot/dev/maskella/common/api/Api.class.php on line 1444
```

Do I need to enclose with`<?xml version='1.0'?> <document></document>`?

Date formats which I have are

21-02-2016 20:14

Date/Time: 09/02 - 15:40

Date: 08/02 - 11:50

Comment: In the example you have complete xml? If it is, yes you have to wrap the string in `<domething></something>`.  `<?xml version='1.0'?>` is not mandatory for your example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the xml doc will need the  header, and will also need a root element which encapsulates the elements from your sudo example.

See [What is the correct format to use for Date/Time in an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254753/what-is-the-correct-format-to-use-for-date-time-in-an-xml-file) for appropriate date formats in XML.