# Force date format through web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I'm invoking a SOAP web service and some fields must respect specific rules.

I have an object with a DateTime field and i want to use it as: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff

The problem occurs when milliseconds value is something like 20.

The value sent to web method is something like: 2017-21-06T18:13:50.**02** instead of 2017-21-06T18:13:50.**020**

When i'm debugging my code, the value of milliseconds is definitely .020000 but looking at SOAP envelops the value passed ignore the zeros on the right.

There is any chance to truncate milliseconds value to always use three digits?

Comment: You say "the problem occurs". What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: Is your service web method receiving this value as a parameter? or are you using a proxy class to consume a web service? how exactly you are passing the value?

Comment: see the next link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254753/what-is-the-correct-format-to-use-for-date-time-in-an-xml-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254753/what-is-the-correct-format-to-use-for-date-time-in-an-xml-file) Hope this help you

Comment: @Jonathan I mean, if milliseconds value is 125, the value passed respect the format i want: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff. If it is, for example, 80, the format used is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ff but i need 3 digits on milliseconds.

Comment: @PastørCortes I'm using a proxy class to do this

Comment: @JavierJimenezMatilla Thanks. I'll check this on my side